# Cast generic class to interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting, clr

I have a problem with casting a generic class to the interface it is implementing.

My code is like this:

```
interface foo
{
    void foobar();
}

class bar: foo
{
    public void foobar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

now I have my factory that creates instances of my classes by the interface, mostly a simple microkernel (service locator). I will simplify it here. Normally it will look up the implementing class from the configs and the factory take the type as T but that doesn't matter for the problem I have.

```
public static class Factory
{


    public static Lazy<foo> CreateLazyInstance()
    {
        Lazy<foo> instance;


        Type type = typeof(bar);

        Type lazyType = typeof(Lazy<>);
        Type toContruct = lazyType.MakeGenericType(type);

        instance = (Lazy<foo>)Activator.CreateInstance(toContruct);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

If will fail at:

```
instance = (Lazy<foo>)Activator.CreateInstance(toContruct);
```

and claim with an InvalidCastException that it is not possible to cast the type `Lazy<bar>` to `Lazy<foo>`.

Is there any way to tell the CLR that this cast will work or to workaround this problem?

Comment: Your bar class does not implement the foo interface. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Icarus: I'd say that's irrelevant.  He just wants to show that he has a class hierarchy with bar implementing foo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) is *invariant* - so a `Lazy<string>` is not a `Lazy<object>` for example. (As pointed out in comments, it couldn't be declared as covariant in `T`, as it's a class, not an interface or delegate.)

However, you can convert one to the other easily enough:

```
static Lazy<TOutput> CreateLazyProxy<TInput, TOutput>
    (Lazy<TInput> input) where TInput : TOutput
{
    return new Lazy<TOutput>(() => input.Value);
}
```

Also, `Func<T>` *is* covariant, so this will work too:

```
static Lazy<TOutput> CreateLazy<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput> func)
    where TInput : TOutput
{
    return new Lazy<TOutput>(func);
}
```

(Not that you particularly need a method for that - if you've *got* a `Func<TInput>`, just construct a `Lazy<TOutput>` directly.)

Comment: It couldn't; it's not an interface.

Comment: @SLaks: you can add a Lazy<out T> interface and have the current class implement that interface.

Comment: @siride: Except that `Lazy<T>` is a BCL class and cannot be modified.

Comment: @SLaks: oops! I can at least be comforted to know that Jon Skeet made a similar mistake.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this would be to pass in a lambda to the Lazy constructor. So, your code would look like the following:

```
  public static Lazy<foo> CreateLazyInstance()
  {
     Type type = typeof(bar);
     return new Lazy<foo>(() => (foo)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must do your foo generic parameter : new():

```
public static Lazy<foo> CreateLazyInstance() where foo : new()
```

And change your code to find a constructor and call it:

```
Type t = typeof(foo);
t.GetConstructor(new type[]{});
return (foo)t.Invoke(new object[]{});
```